# google cloud AI notebook save does not work

Tags: jupyter-lab, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I created  a deep learning instance inside the AI platform of google cloud . I use the built in jupyterlab notebooks running on the browser (I use chrome). Recently I have a problem with saving the code. autosave as well as saving the notebook files does not work. I keep see the message "saving started" when I try to save, but  nothing other than that happens, and the code is not saved. I tried restart the kernel as well as restart the instance but the problem keeps returning. Anyone here encountered the same thing? have a solution?

thanks

Comment: I just got  a file save error message 504. any idea why that is happening?

Comment: What version (Base image) of AI Platform Notebooks are you using (TF 1.15, 2, Pytorch? I can try to replicate it

Comment: Sounds like the kernel isn't being found.  Do you have a live or dead kernel?  If you have a missing / unfound kernel, then you probably have a "version" issue - meaning different versions of the kernel used when the document was created, compared to the version of the kernel that is attempting to open the file.

Comment: @gogasca I use an image with pytorch 1.4

Comment: @Gray. I see the kernel is idle or connected when it happens. what do you think should help when there is versioning problem? restarting didn't work

Comment: Assuming that Anaconda is not involved and causing untraceable issues, I can share a similar problem.  I hate Anaconda, but that's my issue.   I had a similar problem with Jupyter that was caused by a small  change I manually made in the kernel's config file.   I changed the display name to R3.5  from the default display, R.  This change worked well and did not cause a problem until I upgraded the version of R to 3.6.  The new 3.6 R kernel, could display existing Jupyter Notebook files, but nothing else.  A dead kernel.   FYI,  a kernel's name gets registered, and you can re-register  names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked for me eventually was instead of using  https connection I connected to  the instance via ssh and then to accessed jupyterlab in  local host. I followed this link:
https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/jupyter

```
export PROJECT_ID="my-project-id"
export ZONE="my-zone"
export INSTANCE_NAME="my-instance"
gcloud compute ssh --project $PROJECT_ID --zone $ZONE \
$INSTANCE_NAME -- -L 8080:localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I opened a notebook and GCP did not save it,
but after I started the notebook from a folder inside Jupyterlab - it saved it.